# Fresh install: There is no $DefaultLocalBase value set

Tags: machine-learning

Fresh install Mathematica 11.1.1.0 on Windows 10

The command `$DefaultLocalBase` returns `$Failed` and an error message

> LocalObject::lbx: Could not set $DefaultLocalBase to d:\Users\Walter\AppData\Roaming\Wolfram\Objects.

After mathematica install, folder ...\Wolfram\Objects was not in place. Manual creation does not help. Did I miss something while installing? Is there a possibility to set this value?

Seems this is one of  my problems why

```
resource = ResourceObject["MNIST"]

trainingData = ResourceData[resource, "TrainingData"]
```

fails with multiple error messages like

> StringFreeQ::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringFreeQ[FileNameJoin[{FileNameJoin[{LocalObjects`PathName[$Failed],Resources}],16f,16ff8400-2ffb-4642-b626-8e583258924e}],Resources].
>
> LocalObject::uri: FileNameJoin[FileNameSplit[FileNameJoin[{FileNameJoin[{LocalObjects`PathName[$Failed],Resources}],16f,16ff8400-2ffb-4642-b626-8e583258924e}]],OperatingSystem->Unix] is not a valid Local Object URL.
>
> DirectoryQ::fstr: File specification FileNameJoin[{FileNameJoin[{LocalObjects`PathName[$Failed],Resources}],16f,16ff8400-2ffb-4642-b626-8e583258924e}] is not a string of one or more characters.

and so on ....

Appreciate any hint and help.

New status: With the installation of Mathematica 11.2.0 the above problems didn't show up again.